# Remove SSL warning with internal websites

Tags: ssl, google-chrome

I am using a signed SSL certificate generated by our internal CA. I have added subject alternative names so that `myserver.example.net` and `myserver` are both valid for the site. This works correctly in both Firefox and IE, but in Chrome users are still getting a warning message when they use the short name `myserver`.

My question is, Is there any way for users to use `myserver` without getting the SSL warning in Chrome?

Comment: Are you getting a name mismatch warning or something else?

Comment: Is this for a true website or something like OWA for Exchange? Also, with Chrome it should give you a details error as to the rejection or warning. Can you please post that or a screen capture of the error?

Comment: It is odd that IE is fine, but Chrome isn't. Chrome uses the same cert database.

Comment: i get the 'identity of this website cannot be validated' message when accessing the short name. so basically it is telling me that this is an internal website, and cannot be validated by an certificate authority. when using the FQDN - all is well, and i get a normal green padlock.

Comment: Yes. Tell Java to use the Windows certificate store.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using an internal (or non-custom) CA ,you have also the
responsibility to distribute your CA-certificate to the applications
in your organisation.
 
Some applications pick the certificate from a system wide configuration (e.g. `/etc/ssl/certs` below ubuntu). Other like Firefox, Chromium use an own (per application) configuration.

If it works for IE and Firefox, this task seems to be already done for some applications.

For chromium (below linux) you can do this with the following (bash)
code fragment:

```
certificateFile="/etc/MY_CA.cert.pem"
certificateName="Snakeoil Ltd."
if test -d ~/.pki
then
  echo "install '${certificateName}' in for chromium in ~/.pki"
  certutil -A \
     -n "${certificateName}" \
     -t "TCu,Cuw,Tuw" \
     -i ${certificateFile} \
     -d sql:${HOME}/.pki/nssdb
 else
   echo "no user configuration for chromium found"
 fi
```

Some other useful hints for this task are covered here: `http://www.computer42.org/xwiki-static/exported/DevNotes/xwiki.DevNotes.OpenSSL.html`

Comment: thanks for this, but this is a IIS website and Chrome is running on Windows.

Comment: It doesn't depend on the webserver.
Because chrome normally use the windows certificate store there should be no problem if it works with IE (see e.g. http://tig.csail.mit.edu/wiki/TIG/CertificatesChrome). 
Check if your problem is correlated to https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=37142 .